# Error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)', expecting `(', `[', or `{'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, ienumerable, enumerator

I've written some code which disables a script and starts a coroutine when a collision happens, but I get this error
**Assets/Scripts/SceneDelay.cs(16,40): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol ), expecting (, [, or {** 
I have searched up this error but none of the answers help me in my situation, my code seems perfect to me, I don't understand what's wrong with it. Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SceneDelay : MonoBehaviour {

public static int score = 0;
public Text scoreText;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "Obstacle")
    {
        GetComponent(new ScoreScript).enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(DelayLoad());
    }
}

IEnumerator DelayLoad()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    scoreText.text = 0.ToString();
    score = 0;

    yield break;
}
}
```

Comment: `new ScoreScript` => `new ScoreScript()`

Comment: `yield break;` is redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line should be like,

```
GetComponent(new ScoreScript()).enabled = false;
```

you've missed out the () for new instance creation.

Comment: Okay, done, but now it gives me these two errors: **Assets/Scripts/SceneDelay.cs(16,13): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent(System.Type)' has some invalid arguments**.                                                                                    and **Assets/Scripts/SceneDelay.cs(16,26): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `ScoreScript' expression to type `System.Type'**

Comment: Show the actual code which throws the exception. ScoreScript is apparently some other class that you are initiating and it is not a defined System.Type which GetComponent() is expecting. It's the same as if you had a method that expects an integer parameter and you try to pass it some other type such as a string, etc.

Comment: The code is in the question I posted. And how would I change my ScoreScript to a defined System.Type

Comment: @Hanaan328 - I suspect you want something like `GetComponent<ScoreScript>().enabled = false;`